# cron.daily、cron.weekly、cron.d について

Tags: centos, cron

CentOS7で、1週間に一度だけ実行したい処理があるのですが、ファイルは cron.weekly へ配置するのですか？

cron.daily、cron.weekly については、あくまでもそういうファイルを配置することが期待されているだけであって、
やろうと思えば、cron.dailyディレクトリ内に、1週間に一度だけ実行するファイルを配置することも可能ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron.daily` 自体が１日ごと `cron.weekly` 自体が１週間ごとに起動するようになっているはずです。

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/ch-automating_system_tasks

```
#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1                 5                  cron.daily       nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7                 25                 cron.weekly      nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
```

なので原則ダメと考えたらよいです。

- `cron.daily` に１週間に１回起動したいジョブを書くとジョブ自体が自分でタイミングをチェックする必要がある（それをしないための `cron` なので）
- `cron.weekly` に毎日起動したいジョブを書いても１週間に１回しか起動しない